# MySQL SUM function not working for multiple rows order by categori Id

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I want to list total vote poor,fair,good,vgood,excellent,yes,no from my survey_result table but the query only one time loop.

**This is  survey_result  table.**

[image]

**And this is query result**

[image]

```
SELECT
categori.s_categori_id,
categori.categori_name_en,
categori.categori_name_ar,
categori.categori_type,
question.survey_id,
question.question_en,
question.question_ar,
SUM(result.poor) AS poor,
SUM(result.fair ) AS fair,
SUM(result.good) AS good,
SUM(result.vgood) AS vgood,
SUM(result.excellent) AS excellent,
SUM(result.yes) AS yes,
SUM(result.no) As no,
result.comment 
FROM
survey_categori AS categori
INNER JOIN survey_questions AS question ON categori.s_categori_id = 
question.s_categori_id
INNER JOIN survey_result AS result ON result.s_question_id = 
question.survey_id
WHERE
categori.survey_type = 'class'
GROUP BY
question.survey_id
```

Comment: What results are you trying to achieve?  What does this mean: 
 "but the query only one time loop"? As a note:  sample data and desired results as *text* are preferred over screen shots.

Comment: Based on the data shown, the results appear to be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem fixed. There was not same id and same value.

Comment: Consider amending your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add group by below fields that i added in your query

```
categori.s_categori_id,
categori.categori_name_en,
categori.categori_name_ar,
categori.categori_type,
question.survey_id,
question.question_en,
question.question_ar,
SUM(result.poor) AS poor,
SUM(result.fair ) AS fair,
SUM(result.good) AS good,
SUM(result.vgood) AS vgood,
SUM(result.excellent) AS excellent,
SUM(result.yes) AS yes,
SUM(result.no) As no,
result.comment 
FROM
survey_categori AS categori
INNER JOIN survey_questions AS question ON categori.s_categori_id = 
question.s_categori_id
INNER JOIN survey_result AS result ON result.s_question_id = 
question.survey_id
WHERE
categori.survey_type = 'class'
GROUP BY
question.survey_id,categori.categori_name_en,
categori.categori_name_ar,
categori.categori_type,
question.question_en,
question.question_ar
```

Comment: @RamazanZülkarneyn if it helps accept answer please

Answer (score 1):

> I want to list total vote poor,fair,good,vgood,excellent,yes,no from my survey_result table

This sounds like you want the total across the entire survey.  If so, you shouldn't use `GROUP BY`.  To get one row:

```
SELECT SUM(result.poor) AS poor,
       SUM(sr.fair ) AS fair,
       SUM(sr.good) AS good,
       SUM(sr.vgood) AS vgood,
       SUM(sr.excellent) AS excellent,
       SUM(sr.yes) AS yes,
       SUM(sr.no) As no
FROM survey_categori sc INNER JOIN
     survey_questions sq
     ON sc.s_categori_id = sq.s_categori_id INNER JOIN
     survey_result sr
     ON sr.s_question_id = sq.survey_id
WHERE c.survey_type = 'class';
```

You would use `GROUP BY` if you wanted multiple rows in the result set.  Then, every column (or expression) in the `GROUP BY` would (normally) be added to the `SELECT`.  For instance, if you wanted one row per survey, you would have:

```
SELECT sq.survey_id,
       SUM(. . .)
       . . .
FROM . . .
GROUP BY sq.survey_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem fixed. It was because of value I didnt see correct result.